# SSL from Lets Encrypt is not working for www Subdomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

i have a domain lets say example.com

when i type in https://example.com it redirects to a ssl safe version
when i type in example.com or www.example.com it redirects to an unsafe version

example.com and www.example.com should redirect to a safe version

My VPS is from Vultr with Ubuntu and Nginx and i installed an Lets Encrypt Cerrtificate via https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-nginx

can you help me? i followed the instructions and i dont know what went wrong?

Comment: You forgot to mention which server/(reverse)proxy software you're actually using. Is this Apache? Nginx? IIS? `example.com` and `www.example.com` are not the same site in the slightest (in the same way that user1.github.io and user2.github.io are not the same site in the slightest), so you probably had to configure either one to redirect to the other; did you remember to update the server config to make sure the certificate gets used in both instances?

Comment: "can you help me?" Your question not being related to programming, it is offtopic here, please have a look at [su], [sf] or [webmasters.se] but make sure to read their help section to define what questions they are open to, "i followed the instructions" which instructions? when you ask for help, no matter where, you need to show exactly what you did, what you tried (which commands you run) and what results you get vs what you expected "i dont know what went wrong?" based on the details you gave (none) how do you think anyone would be able to tell you what is wrong?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek please remember https://stackoverflow.com/conduct because there was no need for that last sentence. You can explain to people that there are expectations around [asking questions](/help/how-to-ask) without talking down to them.

Comment: The last sentence just explains that there are no details in this question in order to be able to answer it. There is nothing against that and it is certainly not talking down but just explaining what is a good question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and point "what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site. "